# What is the relationship between a regression coefficient and a correlation coefficient?

Tags: regression, correlation

One might expect there to be a formal relationship between a regression coefficient and a correlation coefficient (at least intuitively). Does this relationship change if the distribution of the data is non-gaussian (e.g., bionomial)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\rho=Corr(X,Y)$ For a simple linear regression, $Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X +\epsilon$, you have $\beta_1=\rho \frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}$

Answer (score 0):

@Kamster answer is correct in the univariate case.

If there are more variables then regression coefficient can be thought as a partial correlation coefficient when effects of other variables are controlled.

Comment: Standardized coefficient is indeed closely related (but not equal) to partial correlation: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/76819/3277.

Comment: @ttnphns that is true.