# Distinguishing between Inverse Relationship and similar terms, and precisely understand what Inverse Relationship is

Tags: correlation, terminology, independence

I am not familiar with the statistical terminology (My experience is restricted to Mathematics), and, I am not a native English speaker. In the course of translating an English academic paper, I ran into the term "Inverse Relation", and searches have suggested that what I am referring is, more specifically "Inverse Relationship" (Rather than "Inverse Relation" which has its own, slightly different, to my observation, characteristics.). I specifically approached your members and not the English Forum members in the belief that *Statistics*'s notion of those term would leave no place for doubt.

First, the actual text I am trying to comprehend is

> "...the results indicated that the inattentive aspect of ADHD was **inversely related** to the emotional clarity aspect of...".

I now understand that in such a relationship, the decrease (or increase) of the value standing for **one** variable is followed by the increase (or decrease) of the value standing for **the other**.

**My questions are**:

1. In the specific case in question, would it have made a difference if "Inversely Related" had been replace with "Negatively Related"?
2. Is the case above a case of Inverse Relation, or Inverse Relationship, assuming those two terms are not globally equivalent?
3. Is a given "Inverse Relation(ship)" "invertible", i.e. reversible? To be more clear, is an inverse relation(ship) between two variables independent of the order order of the impact?

Comment: The problem is that the language used was so inexact that what it represents can only be gleaned from the context in which it appears. For more exact language, please see the answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/248688/99274).

Comment: Although I hoped this wasn't the case, I considered the possibility that equivocal terminology was involoved. Thank you for the reference.

Comment: If you want an answer, consider putting the reference in so we can look at it and potentially determine what it is supposed to mean.