# How could I get a correlation value that accounts for gender?

Tags: r, regression, correlation, linear-model, partial-correlation

For instance if I were trying to relate **Age** and **Height**, I would do something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Age, Height)
cor(df)
```

How could I get Pearson's r value and the p-value for the relationship between **Age** and **Height** while accounting for the effect of **Gender**?

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. I had never heard the phrase "partial correlation" before. If you will propose that as the answer (preferably with an example of usage) I will accept it.

Comment: The problem here was not so much "how to use R" but how to find a correlation coefficient while taking another variable into account, which suggests it ought to be on-topic. (I wonder whether we have another thread on partial correlation that this duplicates.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called [partial correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_correlation), basically it, as Wikipedia notices,

> measures the degree of association between two random variables, with
>   the effect of a set of controlling random variables removed

Having correlation coefficients of three variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ we can correct correlation $\rho_{XY}$ by controlling correlations of $X$ and $Y$ with $Z$:

$$ \rho_{XY \cdot Z } = \frac{\rho_{XY} - \rho_{XZ}\rho_{ZY}} {\sqrt{(1-\rho_{XZ}^2) (1-\rho_{ZY}^2)}} $$

This is [related to multiple linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76815/multiple-regression-or-partial-correlation). To test the hypothesis about partial correlation you use $t$-statistic in [similar fashion](http://www.statsdirect.com/help/default.htm#regression_and_correlation/partial_correlation.htm) [as with regular correlation](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org//index.php?title=Partial_correlation_coefficient&oldid=14288) but with $N-3$ degrees of freedom. The same formula can be used for Pearson's or Spearman's correlation coefficients (for more see Altman, 1991 or [Revelle, n.d.](http://www.personality-project.org/r/book/#chapter5)).

There are [multiple R functions and libraries](https://www.google.pl/search?q=partial%20correlation%20r) that enable you to calculate partial correlations like [pcor](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ppcor/), [ggm](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/correlations.html) or [psych](http://personality-project.org/r/html/partial.r.html).

---

Altman, D.G. (1991). *Practical Statistics for Medical Research*. Chapman and Hall, pp. 288-299.

Revelle, W. (n.d.). [Multiple Correlation and Multiple Regression](http://www.personality-project.org/r/book/#chapter5) In: An introduction to psychometric theory with applications in R.

Comment: I think this *could* be on topic if it is more about how this can be done / what it means, as opposed to what R code to use. Can you say more about what kind of thing a partial correlation is & how it works?