# The Book of Why by Judea Pearl: Why is he bashing statistics?

Tags: causality

I am reading *[The Book of Why](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/046509760X)* by Judea Pearl, and it is getting under my skin<sup>1</sup>. Specifically, it appears to me that he is unconditionally bashing "classical" statistics by putting up a [straw man argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man) that statistics is never, ever able to investigate causal relations, that it never is interested in causal relations, and that statistics "became a model-blinded data-reduction enterprise".  Statistics becomes an ugly s-word in his book.

For example:

> Statisticians have been immensely confused about what variables should and should not be controlled for, so the default practice has been to control for everything one can measure. [...] It is a convenient, simple procedure to follow, but it is both wasteful and ridden with errors. A key achievement of the Causal Revolution has been to bring an end to this confusion.
>
> At the same time, statisticians greatly underrate controlling in the sense that they are loath to talk about causality at all [...]

However, causal models have been in statistics like, forever. I mean, a regression model *can* be used essentially a causal model, since we are essentially *assuming* that one variable is the cause and another is the effect (hence correlation is different approach from regression modelling) and testing whether this causal relationship explains the observed patterns.

Another quote:

> No wonder statisticians in particular found this puzzle [The Monty Hall problem] hard to comprehend. They are accustomed to, as R.A. Fisher (1922) put it, "the reduction of data" and ignoring the data-generating process.

This reminds me of [the reply](https://andrewgelman.com/2012/11/10/16808/) Andrew Gelman wrote to [the famous xkcd cartoon](https://xkcd.com/1132/) on Bayesians and frequentists: "Still, I think the cartoon as a whole is unfair in that it compares a sensible Bayesian to a frequentist statistician who blindly follows the advice of shallow textbooks."

The amount of misrepresentation of s-word which, as I perceive it, exists in Judea Pearls book made me wonder whether causal inference (which hitherto I perceived as a useful and interesting way of organizing and testing a scientific hypothesis<sup>2</sup>) is questionable.

**Questions:** do you think that Judea Pearl is misrepresenting statistics, and if yes, why? Just to make causal inference sound bigger than it is? Do you think that causal inference is a Revolution with a big R which really changes all our thinking?

**Edit:**

The questions above are my main issue, but since they are, admittedly, opinionated, please answer these concrete questions (1) what is the meaning of the "Causation Revolution"? (2) how is it different from "orthodox" statistics?

<sub>1. Also because he is *such* a modest guy.

2. I mean in the scientific, not statistical sense.</sub>

**EDIT**: Andrew Gelman wrote [this blog post](https://andrewgelman.com/2019/01/08/book-pearl-mackenzie/) on Judea Pearls book and I think he did a much better job explaining my problems with this book than I did. Here are two quotes:

> On page 66 of the book, Pearl and Mackenzie write that statistics “became a model-blind data reduction enterprise.” Hey! What the hell are you talking about?? I’m a statistician, I’ve been doing statistics for 30 years, working in areas ranging from politics to toxicology. “Model-blind data reduction”? That’s just bullshit. We use models all the time.

And another one:

> Look. I know about the pluralist’s dilemma. On one hand, Pearl believes that his methods are better than everything that came before. Fine. For him, and for many others, they are the best tools out there for studying causal inference. At the same time, as a pluralist, or a student of scientific history, we realize that there are many ways to bake a cake. It’s challenging to show respect to approaches that you don’t really work for you, and at some point the only way to do it is to step back and realize that real people use these methods to solve real problems. For example, I think making decisions using p-values is a terrible and logically incoherent idea that’s led to lots of scientific disasters; at the same time, many scientists do manage to use p-values as tools for learning. I recognize that. Similarly, I’d recommend that Pearl recognize that the apparatus of statistics, hierarchical regression modeling, interactions, poststratification, machine learning, etc etc., solves real problems in causal inference. Our methods, like Pearl’s, can also mess up—GIGO!—and maybe Pearl’s right that we’d all be better off to switch to his approach. But I don’t think it’s helping when he gives out inaccurate statements about what we do.

Comment: Linear regression is not a causal model. Simple linear regression is *the same* as pairwise correlation, the [only difference is standarization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245054/why-is-correlation-not-appropriate-in-situations-when-regression-is/245312#245312). So if you say that regression is causal, then same should be true also for correlation. Is correlation causation? You can use regression to predict whatever, nonsense relations between any arbitrary variables (with many "significant" results by chance).

Comment: Disagreements over which approach to reasoning about causality in statistics has most merit between Pearl, Rubin, Heckman and others appear to have festered, and I do think Pearl's tone is getting ever haughtier. Don't let that distract you from the genuine insight he has to offer. Read his earlier book Causality, it will get under your skin less.

Comment: @CloseToC I would add that Pearl, Rubin and Heckman are in a  way all working within the same framework (i.e., logically equivalent frameworks, see here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/249767/which-theories-of-causality-should-i-know/299090#299090), so their disputes are in a different level from arguing things like "linear regression is a causal model".

Comment: @tim: I am referring to the very thing which is in the comment you quoted: "regression is much more sophisticated model that gives you more information then correlation alone, but the difference is not about appropriateness, but about their utility and the fact that regression provides additional information."

Comment: @January in simple linear regression case, it provides you with no more information then the intercept and $corr(X, Y) \times \;sd(Y)/sd(X)$, so really, nothing special about it.

Comment: I am not saying that it is mathematically special, merely that it is a conceptually [different](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/2129/14803) approach. But uh, OK, I agree, let me edit the question.

Comment: I have been irritated by the book myself. There are some simply false statistical claims there (cannot cite now, the book with my notes in the margins is at home) which made me wonder whether only the journalist who helped Pearl write the book or also Pearl himself was a poor statistician. (Needless to say, I was very surprised to discover such blatant mistakes in a work of such a revered scientist.) His papers are much better, though even there no one would accuse Pearl for modesty...

Comment: I have some concern that this thread already tangles together (a) a specific book from a very smart person (b) that smart person's persona and style of debate (c) whether a particular viewpoint is correct, exaggerated, or whatever.

Comment: @RichardHardy I would be really interested in your margin notes and very grateful if you could post a few in an answer to this question.

Comment: I agree with @NickCox & think it would be better to focus the question a bit more, say on the meaning of & justification for the passage you've quoted rather than on alleged statistician-bashing throughout Pearl's book.

Comment: @Scortchi Maybe, but I was more interested in a general opinion of Judea Pearl's book (whether opinions therein are exaggerated or not, as per point (c) of Nick Cox), not only on the justification of the two passages.

Comment: I read a paper by Pearl, in which there are two "under the null hypothesis" per page on average.

Comment: Ahhh... The "*Black Swan show*" again. A leader of a field not immediately considered part of mainstream Statistics curriculum, writes a popular science book, making opinionated expositions on the shortcoming of mainstream Statistics, employing some degree of generalisations. People feel misunderstood, annoyed, threatened and/or offended. I love this game.

Comment: @usεr11852 well, yeah, I don't feel particularly part of any mainstream Statistics curriculum myself (having done my PhD with a real pipette in hand), but I do feel that his comments are over the top and largely unwarranted.

Comment: Is the question really about the author and not about statistics? I ask because it would be off-topic that way.

Comment: @January: Well, that's the thing - we ask that questions be self-contained, with external references being ancillary. But answerers of this question have to have read the whole book to form a general opinion of it.

Comment: @Firebug: in my opinion I am asking a question on statistics – admittedly, a fairly general one, but statistics is my main issue here. There are sometimes general questions like that.

Comment: Pearl has a very annoying writing style. I had to put the book down after the first chapter. He makes big claims and bashes more than one discipline, all within the first few pages. Reminds me of Nassim Taleb. If his work is so revolutionary, please present clear evidence upfront and make me care, rather than criticize other disciplines.

Comment: @user3132783 you can read his papers here http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/csl_papers.html

Comment: Adding to excellent recommended reading material here, another paper/technical report from Judea Pearl that opened my eyes to why Judea's proposed approach of thinking structurally is much better. It is a unified view of various systematic biases that can occur through simple linear regression examples: http://ftp.cs.ucla.edu/pub/stat_ser/r409-corrected-reprint.pdf. It might take a while to sit down and work things out, but it is definitely worth it.

Comment: I have voted to close this question as opinion based. But I could have also chosen off-topic since I am missing the question that actually relates statistics. @January maybe you could pose the question in a way such that it does *not* become a popularity contest over opinions about a book.

Comment: (Between brackets: just to distill, repeat and emphasize  the questions that are clearly about opinion... Note how you asked your explicit questions: *"**do you think that** Judea Pearl is..."* and *"**Do you think that** causal inference is..."*. These sort of questions have no place here, albeit the many votes, which I guess are more due to the popularity of opinions rather than truly relating to the usefulness of the question/answer. We should not see this correlation as caused by a good question/answer.)

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Well, as it is now it is quite exactly the question I wanted to ask. I already learned a lot from the answers and comments (not to mention tons of interesting references), but I can't see how I can re-formulate the question such that the answers still fit. Therefore I am considering removing the question myself, so if you insist on it, I will do it.

Comment: @January, I can/do not know what kind of considerations were underlying your question, and I haven't read the book in order to propose a twist to your question. Yet, I would suggest you first try some more to improve/refine the question rather than removing it. Maybe you can explain to me, somebody that has not read the book, the problems that you saw in the book (even-though it might have been a gut feeling rather than coming from your brain, you could try to translate it), and such explanation could lead to a pathway for a more confined, as well as more guided/objective, discussion and Q&A.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I don't think that I can do much better than how I already did in the question. I think I will go with the other option.

Comment: Also, I do not feel good with all the attention drawn towards that question. I was hoping for one response tops.

Comment: I would be interested in questions like 'What does the *causality revolution*, mentioned by Judea Pearl, mean?' and 'How is Judea Pearl's *causality revolution* or way of *understanding causality* different from *orthodox statistics*?' (in this latter question the term 'orthodox statistics' might be vague and ambiguous, maybe it just means 'badly applied statistics' according to some?)

Comment: @MartijnWeterings These are both interesting and important questions, but they are not questions which I was interested in. I'd say I remove my question and you add yours, how about that?

Comment: That would remove my vote to close. I get it that you might be more interested in the subjective opinion-based questions. But this does not mean that you can not get closer to an answer on these, indirectly, by means of asking objective, and more strict/confined, questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85978/discussion-between-january-and-martijn-weterings).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is totally no statistics.

Comment: Andrew Gelman on the same topic: https://andrewgelman.com/2019/01/08/book-pearl-mackenzie/

Comment: Yeah, I just read his entry, and I found his comments strangely satisfying. He made a much better job explaining my issue with the book than I did. Here is a quote: "On page 66 of the book, Pearl and Mackenzie write that statistics “became a model-blind data reduction enterprise.” Hey! What the hell are you talking about?? I’m a statistician, I’ve been doing statistics for 30 years, working in areas ranging from politics to toxicology. “Model-blind data reduction”? That’s just bullshit."

Comment: Another opinion by Kevin Gray (from a link on Andrew Gelmans blog): https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/06/gray-pearl-book-of-why.html

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I fully agree that Pearl's tone is arrogant, and his characterisation of "statisticians" is simplistic and monolithic. Also, I don't find his writing particularly clear.

However, I think he has a point.

Causal reasoning was not part of my formal training (MSc): the closest I got to the topic was an elective course in experimental design, i.e. any causality claims required me to physically control the environment. Pearl's book *Causality* was my first exposure to a refutation of this idea. Obviously I can't speak for all statisticians and curricula, but from my own perspective I subscribe to Pearl's observation that causal reasoning is not a priority in statistics.

> It is true that statisticians sometimes control for more variables than is strictly necessary, but this rarely leads to error (at least in my experience).

This is also a belief that I held after graduating with an MSc in statistics in 2010.

However, it is deeply incorrect. When you control for a common effect (called "collider" in the book), you can introduce selection bias. This realization was quite astonishing to me, and really convinced me of the usefulness of representing my causal hypotheses as graphs.

EDIT: I was asked to elaborate on selection bias. This topic is quite subtle, I highly recommend perusing the edX MOOC on [Causal Diagrams](https://www.edx.org/course/causal-diagrams-draw-assumptions-harvardx-ph559x), a very nice introduction to graphs which has a chapter dedicated to selection bias.

For a toy example, to paraphrase [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6089543/) cited in the book: Consider the variables A=attractiveness, B=beauty, C=competence. Suppose that B and C are causally unrelated in the general population (i.e., beauty does not cause competence, competence does not cause beauty, and beauty and competence do not share a common cause). Suppose also that any one of B or C is sufficient for being attractive, i.e. A is a collider. Conditioning on A creates a spurious association between B and C.

A more serious example is the "birth weight paradox", according to which a mother's smoking (S) during pregnancy seems to decrease the mortality (M) of the baby, if the baby is underweight (U). The proposed explanation is that birth defects (D) also cause low birth weight, and also contribute to mortality. The corresponding causal diagram is { S -> U, D -> U, U -> M, S -> M, D -> M } in which U is a collider; conditioning on it introduces the spurious association. The intuition behind this is that if the mother is a smoker, the low birth weight is less likely to be due to a defect.

Comment: +1. Can you elaborate just a little bit more on how it introduces selection bias? Perhaps a little concrete example will make it clear for most readers.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. These are very clear examples.

Comment: So, the intuition for Smokers' Babies' Low Birth Weight, is correct, right?

Comment: @Malandy : this model is consistent with the data, and makes intuitive sense. I don't know whether it is correct.

Comment: FYI https://andrewgelman.com/2019/01/08/book-pearl-mackenzie/

Comment: I had the same sense of surprise when discovering how much trouble controlling for the same variable could get you into. @amoeba, I wrote up an example [here](http://anythingbutrbitrary.blogspot.com/2016/01/how-to-create-confounders-with.html)

Answer (score 82):

Your very question reflects what Pearl is saying!

> a simple linear regression is essentially a causal model

No, a linear regression is a statistical model, not a causal model. Let's assume $Y, X, Z$ are random variables with a multivariate normal distribution. Then you can correctly estimate the linear expectations $E[Y\mid X]$, $E[X\mid Y]$, $E[Y\mid X,Z]$, $E[Z\mid Y, X]$ etc using linear regression, but there's nothing here that says whether any of those quantities are causal.

[A linear structural equation, on the other hand, is a causal model.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/321180/is-the-linearity-assumption-in-linear-regression-merely-a-definition-of-epsilo/321243#321243) But the first step is to understand the difference between statistical assumptions (constraints on the observed joint probability distribution) and causal assumptions (constraints on the causal model).

> do you think that Judea Pearl misrepresenting statistics, and if yes,
>   why?

No, I don't think so, because we see these misconceptions daily. Of course, Pearl is making some generalizations, since some statisticians do work with causal inference (Don Rubin was a pioneer in promoting potential outcomes... also, I am a statistician!). But he is correct in saying that the bulk of traditional statistics education shuns causality, even to formally *define* what a causal effect is.

To make this clear, if we ask a statistician/econometrician with just a regular training to define mathematically what is the expected value of $Y$ if we intervene on $X$, he would probably write $E[Y|X]$ [(see an example here)](https://fxdiebold.blogspot.com/2014/01/causality-and-t-consistency-vs.html)! But that's an observational quantity, that's not how you *define* a causal effect! In other terms, currently, a student with just a traditional statistics course lacks even the ability of properly defining this quantity mathematically ($E[Y_{x}]$ or $E[Y|do(x)]$) if you are not familiar [with the structural/counterfactual theory of causation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/249767/which-theories-of-causality-should-i-know/299090#299090)!

The quote you bring from the book is also a great example. You will not find in traditional statistics books a correct definition of what a confounder is, nor guidance about when you should (or should not) adjust for a covariate in observational studies. In general, you see “correlational criteria”, such as “if the covariate is associated with the treatment and with the outcome, you should adjust for it”. One of the most notable examples of this confusion shows up in [Simpson’s Paradox—when faced with two estimates of opposite signs, which one should you use, the adjusted or unadjusted?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/316319/does-simpsons-paradox-cover-all-instances-of-reversal-from-a-hidden-variable/318471#318471) The, answer, of course, depends on the causal model.

And what does Pearl mean when he says that this question was brought to an end? In the case of simple adjustment via regression, he is referring to the [backdoor criterion (see more here)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188557/omitted-variable-bias-which-predictors-do-i-need-to-include-and-why/312138#312138). And for identification in general---beyond simple adjustment---he means that we now have [complete algorithms for identification of causal effects for any given semi-markovian DAG.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211008/dox-operator-meaning/312130#312130)

Another remark here is worth making. ***Even in experimental studies*** — where traditional statistics has surely done a lot of important work with the design of experiments!— [***in the end of the day you still need a causal model***.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2245/statistics-and-causal-inference/310919#310919)  Experiments can suffer from lack of compliance, from loss of follow up, from selection bias... also, most of the time you don't want to confine the results of your experiments to the specific population you analyzed, [you want to generalize your experimental results to a broader/different population](http://www.pnas.org/content/113/27/7345). Here, again, one may ask: what should you adjust for? Are the data and substantive knowledge you have enough to allow such extrapolation? All of these are causal concepts, thus you need a language to formally express causal assumptions and check whether they are enough to allow you to do what you want!

In sum, these misconceptions are widespread in statistics and econometrics, there are several examples here in Cross Validated, such as:

- [understanding what a confounder is](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59369/confounder-definition/298750#298750)
- [understanding which variables you should include in a regression (for estimating causal effects)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312138/39630)
- [understanding that even if you include *all* variables a regression may not be causal](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/373385/is-a-regression-causal-if-there-are-no-omitted-variables/373388#373388)
- [understanding the difference between (lack of) statistical associations and causation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357255/does-statistical-independence-mean-lack-of-causation/357275#357275)
- [defining a causal model and causal effects](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/306188/39630)

And many more.

> Do you think that causal inference is a Revolution with a big R which
>   really changes all our thinking?

Considering the current state of affairs in many sciences, how much we have advanced and how fast things are changing, and how much we can still do, I would say this is indeed a revolution.

***PS***: Pearl suggested two of his posts on UCLA's causality blog that will be of interest to this discussion, you can find the posts [here](http://causality.cs.ucla.edu/blog/index.php/2018/06/11/statisticians-reaction-to-the-book-of-why/) and [here](http://causality.cs.ucla.edu/blog/index.php/2018/06/15/a-statisticians-re-reaction-to-the-book-of-why/).

***PS 2***: As January has mentioned in his new edit, Andrew Gelman has a [new post](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2019/01/08/book-pearl-mackenzie/) in his blog. In addition to the debate on Gelman's blog, Pearl has also answered on twitter (below):

> Gelman's review of #Bookofwhy
>   should be of interest because it represents an attitude that paralyzes
>   wide circles of statistical researchers. My initial reaction is now
>   posted on https://t.co/mRyDcgQtEc Related
>   posts: https://t.co/xUwR6eCGrZ
>   and https://t.co/qwqV3oyGUy
>
> — Judea Pearl (@yudapearl) January
>   9, 2019

Comment: Thank you. But – well, writing simplistically, I can calculate E[X|Y] as well as E[Y|X], but I can write X←Y as well as X→Y in a DAG. One way or other, I *must* start with a scientific hypothesis or a model. My hypothesis, my model – my choice. The very fact that I *can* do something doesn't mean I should do it, does it.

Comment: @January it doesn't mean you should, the point here is only about being able to  articulate accurately what you want to estimate (the causal estimand), articulate accurately your causal assumptions (making clear the distinction of causal and statistical assumptions), checking the logical implications of those causal assumptions and being able to understand whether your causal assumptions + data are enough for answering your query.

Comment: I completely agree, but I don't see here a fundamental, philosophical difference between using a DAG or using a linear model. You can use both badly, or you can use both to test a reasonable scientific causal hypothesis (if that weren't possible for linear models, we would not be having any modern drugs or vaccines today).

Comment: @January say you have an observational study and want to estimate the causal effect of $X$ on $Y$. How do you decide which covariates to include in your regression?

Comment: I did read the criticism on how "orthodox statisticians" do it. However, not being a statistician (orthodox or otherwise) myself, I can only say: well, it seems to work. What is the fundamental difference between making decisions which covariates to include in a linear model and making decisions which covariates include in a DAG?

Comment: @January we (scientists) can do a lot of causal inference in our heads pretty well. What we are discussing here is how to mathematically (and efficiently) represent causal knowledge.

Comment: @January like with all mathematics, simply because it's easy to get things wrong when we do not write our assumptions down. See here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59369/confounder-definition/298750#298750 how many people still do not understand what a confounder is (including an example of a  published statistics paper).

Comment: I completely agree, that is why I wrote that I perceive CI as a way of ordering scientific reasoning. But it is one thing to say: here is a very clever way of pinning down your assumptions, and another to say: that is a Revolution, because before that we were not able to grasp causality at all.

Comment: @CarlosCinelli: Your comment above - "say you have an observational study and want to estimate the causal effect of X on Y. How do you decide which covariates to include in your regression?" bears directly on the quotation from Pearl's book given in the question, & it might be worth expanding on it a little in your answer.

Comment: @Scortchi you mean you would like me to explain a bit the backdoor criterion in this post?

Comment: I think so: it doesn't seem entirely unfair to suggest that your average statistician, while likely well versed in causal inference from controlled experiments, & certainly in no danger of confusing correlation with causation, might be a bit shaky on causal inference from observational data. I take the last to be the context of the quotation (I haven't read the book) & it's something that some readers of this post may not pick up on.

Comment: @Scortchi ok will do it, will also complement other things in light of the other answers, but probably only in the end of the day, have some meetings now!

Comment: @January **"What is the fundamental difference between making decisions which covariates to include in a linear model and making decisions which covariates include in a DAG?"** There are confounders, the inclusion of which via adjustment (covariates) or stratified analyses, actually *bias* causal estimates. See, for example, Figure 5 and the accompanying text on harmful adjustment in Greenland, S., Pearl, J., and Robins, J. M. (1999). [Causal diagrams for epidemiologic research](https://www.jstor.org/tc/accept?origin=%2Fstable%2Fpdf%2F3702180.pdf). *Epidemiology*, 10(1):37–48.

Comment: @January In short "adjusting for covariates" ***does not*** necessarily mean you have eliminated bias in causal effect estimates from those variables.

Comment: @Alexis: Again, a key point IMO.

Comment: @Scortchi I updated the answer, with some points on identification in observational studies, but also pointing out that even in experiments we need causal models---for instance, if you want to generalize an experimental study to a different population, what covariates should you adjust for?

Comment: I think its fair to say that econometricians have been (on average) more focused causal inference than statisticians, and more focused on it than you give them credit for. There has been a causal revolution, but Pearl is only part of the story.

Comment: @CarlosCinelli, regarding your edit 14 hours ago: how cool!!

Comment: @MichaelBishop (also Carlos Cinelli!) I have [posed a question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/559240) about different 'parts of the story' in the Causal Revolution, and I suspect one or both of you might have an insight for a comment or even an asnwer there. Very best to you both.

Answer (score 30):

I'm a fan of Judea's writing, and I've read Causality (love) and Book of Why (like).

I do not feel that Judea is bashing statistics. It's hard to hear criticism. But what can we say about any person or field that doesn't take criticism? They tend from greatness to complacency. You must ask: is the criticism correct, needed, useful, and does it propose alternatives? The answer to all those is an emphatic "Yes".

Correct? I've reviewed and collaborated on a few dozen papers, mostly analyses of observational data, and I rarely feel there is a sufficient discussion of causality. The "adjustment" approach involves selecting variables because they were hand-picked from the DD as being "useful" "relevant" "important" or other nonsense.$^1$

Needed? The media is awash with seemingly contradictory statements about the health effects of major exposures. Inconsistency with data analysis has stagnated evidence which leaves us lacking useful policy, healthcare procedures, and recommendations for better living.

Useful? Judea's comment is pertinent and specific enough to give pause. It is directly relevant to any data analysis any statistician or data expert might encounter.

Does it propose alternatives? Yes, Judea in fact discusses the possibility of advanced statistical methods, and even how they reduce to known statistical frameworks (like Structural Equation Modeling) and their connection to regression models). It all boils down to requiring an explicit statement of the content knowledge that has guided the modeling approach.

Judea isn't simply suggesting we defenestrate all statistical methods (e.g. regression). Rather, he is saying that we need to embrace some causal theory to justify models.

$^1$ the complaint here is about the use of convincing and imprecise language to justify what is ultimately the wrong approach to modeling. There can be overlap, serendipitously, but Pearl is clear about the purpose of a causal diagram (DAG) and how variables can be classified as "confounders".

Comment: Nice answer. Note that not being a statistician but having served as an interface between statistics and biology for many years, for me any criticism of statisticians is really not so hard to hear ;-) However, do you really think that "orthodox statistics" cannot handle causality at all, as Pearl explicitly states?

Comment: @January *au contraire*. I think that the deficiency among statisticians in accepting the causal inference in their analyses is directly related to their deficiency in understanding frequentist inference. It's the counterfactual reasoning that lacks.

Comment: +1 "The "adjustment" approach involves selecting variables because they were hand-picked from the DD as being "useful" "relevant" "important" or other nonsense **without actually incorporating formal hypotheses about the specific causal relationships among them (*a la* the formal use of DAGs)** ." Edit added. :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85815/discussion-on-answer-by-adamo-the-book-of-why-by-judea-pearl-why-is-he-bashing).

Comment: Just a note of appreciation upon a return to this question and your answer to it. :) Specifically the list of one-word questions/values that your explore.

Answer (score 27):

I haven't read this book, so I can only judge the particular quote you give.  However, even on this basis, I agree with you that this seems extremely unfair to the statistical profession.  I actually think that statisticians have always done a remarkably good job at stressing the distinction between statistical associations (correlation, etc.) and causality, and warning against the conflation of the two.  Indeed, in my experience, statisticians have generally been *the primary professional force* fighting against the ubiquitous confusion between cause and correlation.  It is outright false (and virtually slander) to claim that statisticians are "...loath to talk about causality at all."  I can see why you are annoyed reading arrogant horseshit like this.

I would say that it is reasonably common for *non-statisticians* who use statistical models to have a poor understanding of the relationship between statistical association and causality.  Some have good scientific training from other fields, in which case they may also be well aware of the issue, but there are certainly some people who use statistical models who have a poor grasp of these issues.  This is true in many applied scientific fields where practitioners have basic training in statistics, but do not learn it at a deep level.  In these cases it is often professional statisticians who alert other researchers to the distinctions between these concepts and their proper relationship.  Statisticians are often the key designers of RCTs and other experiments involving controls used to isolate causality.  They are often called on to explain protocols such as randomisation, placebos, and other protocols that are used to try to sever relationships with potential confounding variables.  It is true that statisticians sometimes control for more variables than is strictly necessary, but this rarely leads to error (at least in my experience).  I think most statisticians are aware of the difference between [confounding variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confounding) and [collider variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collider_(epidemiology)) when they do regression analysis with a view to causal inferences, and even if they are not always building perfect models, the notion that they somehow eschew consideration of causality is simply ridiculous.

I think Judea Pearl has made a very valuable contribution to statistics with his work on causality, and I am grateful to him for this wonderful contribution.  He has constructed and examined some very useful formalisms that help to isolate causal relationships, and his work has become a staple of a good statistical education.  I read his book [*Causality*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052189560X) while I was a grad student, and it is on my shelf, and on the shelves of many other statisticians.  Much of this formalism echoes things that have been known intuitively to statisticians since before they were formalised into an algebraic system, but it is very valuable in any case, and goes beyond that which is obvious.  (I actually think in the future we will see a merging of the "do" operation with probability algebra occurring at an axiomatic level, and this will probably eventually become the core of probability theory.  I would love to see this built directly into statistical education, so that you learn about causal models and the "do" operation when you learn about probability measures.)

One final thing to bear in mind here is that there are many applications of statistics where the goal is *predictive*, where the practitioner is not seeking to infer causality.  These types of applications are extremely common in statistics, and in such cases, it is important **not** to restrict oneself to causal relationships.  This is true in most applications of statistics in finance, HR, workforce modelling, and many other fields.  One should not underestimate the amount of contexts where one cannot or should not seek to control variables.

---

**Update:** I notice that my answer disagrees with the one provided by [Carlos](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/39630/carlos-cinelli).  Perhaps we disagree on what constitutes "a statistician/econometrician with just a regular training".  Anyone who I would call a "statistician" usually has at least a graduate-level education, and usually has substantial professional training/experience.  (For example, in Australia, the requirement to become an "Accredited Statistician" with our national professional body requires a minimum of four years experience after an honours degree, or six years experience after a regular bachelors degree.)  In any case, a student studying statistics *is not a statistician*.

I notice that as evidence of the alleged lack of understanding of causality by statisticians, Carlos's answer points to several questions on CV.SE which ask about causality in regression.  In every one of these cases, the question is asked by someone who is obviously a novice (not a statistician) and the answers given by Carlos and others (which reflect the correct explanation) are highly-upvoted answers.  Indeed, in several of the cases Carlos has given a detailed account of the causality and his answers are the most highly up-voted.  This surely proves that statisticians *do understand causality*.

Some other posters have pointed out that analysis of causality is often not included in the statistics curriculum.  That is true, and it is a great shame, but most professional statisticians are not recent graduates, and they have learned far beyond what is included in a standard masters program.  Again, in this respect, it appears that I have a higher view of the average level of knowledge of statisticians than other posters.

Comment: I am a non-statistician whose formal training in statistics was by non-statisticians in the same field, and I teach and research with non-statisticians applying statistics. I can assure you that the principle that (e.g.) correlation is not causation is, and was, a recurrent mantra in my field. Indeed I don't come across people who can't see that a correlation between rainfall and wheat yield isn't all that needs to be said about the relationship between them and the underlying processes. Typically, in my experience, non-statisticians too have thought this through long since.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I guess I would say that it is even less common for professional statisticians to confuse correlation and cause than for non-statisticians, so when this happens, it is usually by the latter.  In short, $\mathbb{P}(\text{Confused}|\text{Non-statistician})$ may be low, but $\mathbb{P}(\text{Non-statistician}|\text{Confused})$ is high.

Comment: As an epidemiologist, I'm getting more and more annoyed by this mantra. As @NickCox says, this is something that even non-scientists understand. The problem I have is when everyone jumps on the bandwagon of "correlation does not mean causation!" whenever an observational study (a case-control study, say) is published. Yes, correlation does not mean causation but the researchers are usually quite aware of that and will do everything to design and analyze a study in such a way that a causal interpretation is at least plausible.

Comment: Sorry, but I still disagree. My colleagues using statistics are usually at pains to emphasise that they are in no sense strong on statistics but I've never encountered one who wouldn't regard establishing processes and mechanisms independently of statistical analysis as central to the study of causation or who is confused on this point. Many textbooks are full of silly stories of correlations that are spurious and this is teaching that is absorbed.

Comment: @Nick Cox: I have edited to more accurately state that there are many non-statisticians who understand this well.  It was not my intention to cast dispersions over other professions - only to stress that the issue is *extremely* well understood by statisticians.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'll let previous comments stand for the moment.

Comment: @NickCox There's a lot more to Pearl's contributions about causality than "correlation is not causation".  I'm with Carlos here.  There's enough to learn about causality that it should be a whole course.  As far as I know, most statistics departments don't offer such a course.

Comment: @NeilG Indeed yes; my comment is addressed to this answer, not the question.

Comment: @Ben : Pearl does not accuse statisticians of confusing correlation and causation. He accuses them of mostly steering clear of causal reasoning. I agree with you that his tone is arrogant, but I think he has a point.

Comment: From what I can tell, statisticians certainly tackle causality. However, they usually do it in situations that can be described with a very simple DAG, and they just use intuition to determine what variable you should control. I have never seen a formal way of treating causality in statistics until reading Pearl's structural causal model (which can be a limitation of my own scope). From what I can tell, statisticians always know when causality *isn't* implied, but they don't do a lot of work to try and determine when it is.

Comment: @mitchus: My answer gives a direct quote of what Pearl says, that I object to (taken from the OP's question).  He says that statisticians are "...loath to talk about causality at all."  I note that this is false, and that statisticians are regularly on the forefront of the effort to convince *other people* not to confuse correlation with cause (something they clearly could not do without talking about cause).

Comment: @Ben : that is exactly Pearl's point. When statisticians talk about causality, it's usually to tell people that correlation does not imply causation, and they do so because their methods focus on correlation rather than causation.

Comment: @mitchus: It is totally ridiculous to say that statisticians ignore cause, and cite as evidence the fact that they regularly warn that correlation does not imply cause.  That latter statement implies discussion of *both* issues.  As to methods, cause is inferred (just as in Pearl's theory) from statistical associations that occur in the outcomes of certain experimental structures.

Comment: @Ben : what are the most commonly used statistical methods, and to what extent do they incorporate causal reasoning?

Comment: @mitchus: That sounds like a question you could post as an entire question in this forum (and even then, it would probably be closed as too broad).  You cannot seriously expect me to answer such a broad question in a comment can you?

Comment: @Bridgeburners "From what I can tell, statisticians always know when causality isn't implied, but they don't do a lot of work to try and determine when it is." **This *so* hard!**

Comment: Ben - Reinstate Monica, perhaps as a response to @mitchus you could simply provide a citation of a textbook (or other resource) authored by a statistician that provides the same depth of ***formal* causal inference** as provided by Pearl (or either of the Glymours, Robbins, Greenland, Hernán, etc.)?

Comment: @Alexis: There is no reason such a reference is required to demonstrate my point.  I have not claimed the anyone has *formalised* causal reasoning in more depth than Pearl.

Comment: @Ben Can you show a statistician widely recognized as such who *has* formalized counterfactual causal inference even only *as much as* the degree that Pearl has (not "in more depth than")? Because the folks whinging that Pearl is "bashing statistics" seem mightly silent on that specific point to me: Pearl (and the other CFCR folks like Glymour, Robbins & Hernán, etc.) seem to me to be doing something quite different than what statistics textbooks do… sez me in a moment of grousishness. :) I am *happy* to receive evidence to the contrary.

Comment: Again, you are asking me to demonstrate something *I have not claimed*.  If you read my answer you will see that I have specifically drawn attention to the fact that Pearl formalised causal theory in a way that has added a greater contribution to statistical education.  I do not understand why you continue to demand that I prove a claim I have not made; so yes, it does seem like grousishness.

Comment: (As a secondary matter, can't both claims be right here?  I.e., Pearl has added valuable new formalism to causal theory, and thereby advanced the field, but he has also "bashed statistics" unreasonably with exaggerated claims.  The specific remark I quote in my answer appears to me to be a clear instance of the latter.)

Answer (score 12):

> a simple linear regression is essentially a causal model

Here's an example I came up with where a linear regression model fails to be causal. Let's say *a priori* that a drug was taken at time 0 (*t=0*) and that *it has no effect on the rate of heart attacks at* *t=1*. Heart attacks at *t=1* affect heart attacks at *t=2* (i.e. previous damage makes the heart more susceptible to damage). Survival at *t=3* only depends on whether or not people had a heart attack at *t=2* -- heart attack at t=1 realistically would affect survival at *t=3*, but we won't have an arrow, for the sake of simplicity.

Here's the legend:

[image: DAG legend]

Here's the true causal graph:
[image: collider bias]

Let's pretend that we don't know that heart attacks at *t=1* are independent of taking the drug at *t=0* so we construct a simple linear regression model to estimate the effect of the drug on heart attack at *t=0*. Here our predictor would be *Drug t=0* and our outcome variable would be *Heart Attack t=1*. The only data we have is people who survive at *t=3*, so we'll run our regression on that data.

Here's the 95% Bayesian credible interval for coefficient of *Drug t=0*:
[image: 95% credible interval, collider bias]

Much of the probability as we can see is greater than 0, so it looks like there's an effect! **However, we know *a priori* that there is 0 effect.** The mathematics of causation as developed by Judea Pearl and others make it much easier to see that there will be bias in this example (due to conditioning on a descendant of a collider). Judea's work implies that in this situation, we should use the full data set (i.e. don't look at the people who only survived), which will remove the biased paths:

[image: no bias]

Here's the 95% Credible Interval when looking at the full data set (i.e. not conditioning on those who survived).

[image: 95% credible interval, no bias].

It is densely centered at 0, which essentially shows no association at all.

In real-life examples, things might not be so simple. There may be many more variables that might cause systematic bias (confounding, selection bias, etc.). What to adjust for in analyses has been mathematized by Pearl; algorithms can suggest which variable to adjust for, or even tell us when adjusting is not enough to remove systematic bias. With this formal theory set in place, we don't need to spend so much time arguing about what to adjust for and what not to adjust for; we can quickly reach conclusions as to whether or not our results are sound. We can design our experiments better, we can analyze observational data more easily.

Here's [a freely-available course online on Causal DAGs](https://www.edx.org/course/causal-diagrams-draw-assumptions-harvardx-ph559x) by Miguel Hernàn. It has a bunch of real-life case studies where professors / scientists / statisticians have come to opposite conclusions about the question at hand. Some of them might seem like paradoxes. However, you can easily solve them via Judea Pearl's *d-separation* and *backdoor-criterion*.

For reference, here's code to the data-generating process and the code for credible intervals shown above:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels as sm
import pymc3 as pm
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

%matplotlib inline

# notice that taking the drug is independent of heart attack at time 1.
# heart_attack_time_1 doesn't "listen" to take_drug_t_0
take_drug_t_0 = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=0.7, size=10000)
heart_attack_time_1 = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=0.4, size=10000)

proba_heart_attack_time_2 = []

# heart_attack_time_1 increases the probability of heart_attack_time_2. Let's say
# it's because it weakens the heart and makes it more susceptible to further
# injuries
# 
# Yet, take_drug_t_0 decreases the probability of heart attacks happening at
# time 2
for drug_t_0, heart_attack_t_1 in zip(take_drug_t_0, heart_attack_time_1):
    if drug_t_0 == 0 and heart_attack_t_1 == 0:
        proba_heart_attack_time_2.append(0.1)
    elif drug_t_0 == 1 and heart_attack_t_1 == 0:
        proba_heart_attack_time_2.append(0.1)
    elif drug_t_0 == 0 and heart_attack_t_1 == 1:
        proba_heart_attack_time_2.append(0.5)
    elif drug_t_0 == 1 and heart_attack_t_1 == 1:
        proba_heart_attack_time_2.append(0.05)

heart_attack_time_2 = np.random.binomial(
    n=2, p=proba_heart_attack_time_2, size=10000
)

# people who've had a heart attack at time 2 are more likely to die by time 3

proba_survive_t_3 = []
for heart_attack_t_2 in heart_attack_time_2:
    if heart_attack_t_2 == 0:
        proba_survive_t_3.append(0.95)
    else:
        proba_survive_t_3.append(0.6)

survive_t_3 = np.random.binomial(
    n=1, p=proba_survive_t_3, size=10000
)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'survive_t_3': survive_t_3,
        'take_drug_t_0': take_drug_t_0,
        'heart_attack_time_1': heart_attack_time_1,
        'heart_attack_time_2': heart_attack_time_2
    }
)

# we only have access to data of the people who survived
survive_t_3_data = df[
    df['survive_t_3'] == 1
]

survive_t_3_X = survive_t_3_data[['take_drug_t_0']]

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(survive_t_3_X, survive_t_3_data['heart_attack_time_1'])
lr.coef_

with pm.Model() as collider_bias_model_normal:
    alpha = pm.Normal(name='alpha', mu=0, sd=1)
    take_drug_t_0 = pm.Normal(name='take_drug_t_0', mu=0, sd=1)
    summation = alpha + take_drug_t_0 * survive_t_3_data['take_drug_t_0']
    sigma = pm.Exponential('sigma', lam=1)           

    pm.Normal(
        name='observed', 
        mu=summation,
        sd=sigma,
        observed=survive_t_3_data['heart_attack_time_1']
    )

    collider_bias_normal_trace = pm.sample(2000, tune=1000)

pm.plot_posterior(collider_bias_normal_trace['take_drug_t_0'])

with pm.Model() as no_collider_bias_model_normal:
    alpha = pm.Normal(name='alpha', mu=0, sd=1)
    take_drug_t_0 = pm.Normal(name='take_drug_t_0', mu=0, sd=1)
    summation = alpha + take_drug_t_0 * df['take_drug_t_0']
    sigma = pm.Exponential('sigma', lam=1)           

    pm.Normal(
        name='observed', 
        mu=summation,
        sd=sigma,
        observed=df['heart_attack_time_1']
    )

    no_collider_bias_normal_trace = pm.sample(2000, tune=2000)

pm.plot_posterior(no_collider_bias_normal_trace['take_drug_t_0'])
```

Answer (score 4):

Two papers, the second a classic, that help (I think) shed additional lights on Judea's points and this topic more generally. This comes from someone who has used SEM (which is correlation and regression) repeatedly and resonates with his critiques:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022103111001466

http://psycnet.apa.org/record/1973-20037-001

Essentially the papers describe why correlational models (regression) can not ordinarily be taken as implying any strong causal inference. Any pattern of associations can fit a given covariance matrix (i.e., non specification of direction and or relationship among the variables). Hence the need for such things as an experimental design, counterfactual propositions, etc. This even applies when one has a temporal structure to their data where the putative cause occurs in time before the putative effect.

Answer (score 3):

"...since we are essentially assuming that one variable is the cause and another is the effect (hence correlation is different approach from regression modelling)..."

Regression modeling most definitely does NOT make this assumption.

"... and testing whether this causal relationship explains the observed patterns."

If you are assuming causality and validating it against observations, your are doing SEM modeling, or what Pearl would call SCM modeling.  Whether or not you want to call that part of the domain of stats is debatable.  But I think most wouldn't call it classical stats.

Rather than dumping on stats in general, I believe Pearl is just criticizing statistician's reticence to address causal semantics.  He considers this a serious problem because of what Carl Sagan calls the "get in and get out" phenomenon, where you drop a study that says "meat consumption 'strongly associated' with increased libido, p < .05" and then bows out knowing full well the two outcomes are going to be causally linked in the mind of the public.