# Relation Between Partial Correlation and Beta Coefficient in Multiple Regression

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, partial-correlation

Suppose I've a multiple regression coefficient in the following form:

```
y = β0 + β1x1 + β2x2 + β3x3 + β4x4 + ϵ
```

My question is how to calculate the relationship between partial correlation and beta coefficient in this case. The question is an extension of the following [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76815/multiple-regression-or-partial-correlation). In this question @ttnphns showed the equation from where we can calculate beta coefficients from partial correlations. But he showed it in 2-predictor situation. I want to know if it can be extended to n-predictor situation.

Comment: Actually, nothing changes principally when there is 2+ predictors. I've added the general formula to my answer there.

Comment: @ttnphns: Thanks for your answer! This was really helpful. I was looking for it for quite a long time.

Comment: Yes..Now this question has become duplicate  :)