# partial correlation for logistic regression

Tags: logistic, references, causality, partial-correlation

I am looking for an equivalent of partial correlation but for logistic regression. I.e., I want to have a measure of an effect a variable have on the outcome, independent of other variables in the model, that is scaled between -1 and 1. References would also be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to compute standardized coefficients, standardizing both by the standard deviation of the corresponding predictor and the standard deviation of $y^*$, the latent continuous variable underlying the binary outcome. [Standardized coefficients do not have the same interpretation as partial correlations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76815/multiple-regression-or-partial-correlation-coefficient-and-relations-between-th), but they are a scale-free way of describing the relationship between a predictor and the outcome conditional on the other covariates.

Another method would be to use one of the [pseudo-$R^2$ measures](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-what-are-pseudo-r-squareds/) available for logistic regression and compute the change in the pseudo-$R^2$ corresponding to removing each predictor from the full model while keeping other predictors in the model, which is how the squared semi-partial correlation is computed in linear regression. McKelvey & Zavoina's $R^2$ is a nice choice because it also relies on the continuous latent variable $y^*$.

Comment: do you have any more information/references about using pseudo r2 as a  pseudo partial correlation measures? I understand the concept, but i didn't see it being used in the wild and i would like to cite something

Comment: I don't have any references for this, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It is not related with partial correlation, but something you can do to measure the effect a variable has on the outcome of logistic regressions is the [Odds Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_ratio) statistic.

It can be interpreted as follow: *for a one-unit increase in your continuous predictor variable, the odds of the dependent variable being positive (=1) increase by factor x*. If you have a OR of 1.5 if means that a one unit increase in the continuous variable leads to a 50% increase in the odds of the event.

The odds ratio of each variable can be obtained by the exponentiation of the trained model coefficients.

Comment: thanks for your response. OR is fine, but i want some unit-less measure that is comparable to partial cor.