# Compare effects in a small sample

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, model-comparison, partial-correlation

I would like to analyse whether measures *A*, *B*, and *C* have a different influence on a measure D compared to a measure *X* on *D*. My exploratory hypothesis is that *A*, *B*, or *C* could influence *Z* negatively while *X* positively influences *Z*.

Additionally, I need to account for covariates. While the most obvious way would be to compare coefficients in a linear model, my small sample size requires me to serach for alternative analyses.

I received a recommendation to use the `cocor`  R package for comparing partial correlation coefficients. This package mplements a z-test to compare the correlations between *A~D* and *X~D* (andother combinations) while correcting for the intercorrelation between *A~X*.

However, I have some doubts and questions regarding this analysis:

1. Is this approach more powerful than using regression models, or is it similar (since I am correcting here for covariates as well)?
2. To match the polarity between *A*, *B*, *C*, and X, I reversed the sign of *X*. My intention was to compare coefficients that have the same direction (+.3 means the same as +.4). However, the `cocor`  z-test works with the difference between the two correlations, leading to different results (e.g., -.50 -(.30)= -.80 vs.   -.50 -(-.30) = -.20!).
   I wonder if this kind of test is even meaningful in this context.

Comment: In my understanding, partial correlations are not more powerful than multiple regression , they are more or less the same thing. [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76815/multiple-regression-or-partial-correlation-coefficient-and-relations-between-th) may help. What is your sample size? Comparing correlation coefficients within a small sample seems doesn't seem like a good idea to me but I may be wrong.

Comment: How small is your sample? How many covariates?  But, in general, you can't get around the small sample size by using different methods.  HOWEVER, you might try a permutation test.

Comment: Sample size is 24  @Sointu

Comment: Number of covariates ranges between 1 and 6 (plus the 2 predictors of interest) depending on the predictors and dependent variables.. @PeterFlom

Answer (score 0):

With 24 observations, you are going to be very limited. Even just the 2 predictors is running the risk of overfitting. Adding covariates will make it very very likely to overfit.

There is an old book by Rick Hoyle called *Statistical Strategies for Small Sample Research* that might help, but I read the book 20 years ago and don't remember exactly what's in it.